# How to extract index position of minimum list value?

Tags: python, numpy

So, I have this code.
How to get the index  of the minimum list value

```
import numpy as np
dict1={"num1":(9,6,6,9),"num2":(9,9,6,6)}
testnum=(10,5,5,10)
listdict= list(map(lambda x:x, dict1.values()))
result = np.array(listdict)-np.array(testnum)
print("result:",result)
print("len :",len(result))
```

print:

```
result: [[-1  1  1 -1]
       [-1  4  1 -4]]
len: 2
```

By just viewing it, I can point that index 0 of result has the minimum value.
How to get the index position?
Any idea on this?

target:

```
min [[-1  1  1 -1]
index 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `min` function:

```
import numpy as np
dict1={"num1":(9,6,6,9),"num2":(9,9,6,6)}
testnum=(10,5,5,10)
listdict= list(map(lambda x:x, dict1.values()))
result = min(np.array(listdict)-np.array(testnum), key=sum)
index = (np.array(listdict)-np.array(testnum)).tolist().index(result.tolist())
print("result:",result)
print("index:",index)
```

Output:

```
result: [-1  1  1 -1]
index: 0
```

Comment: How about the index ?

Answer (score 2):

You can print the position of the min of a list without much extra manipulation:

```
testnum = (1,2,10,20,10,5)
print(testnum.index(min(testnum)))
```